# check_disk not generating alerts: nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, health-monitoring

I am new to nagios.

I am trying to configure the "check_disk" service for one host but I am not getting the expected results.

I should get the emails when when disk usage goes beyond 80%.

So, There is already service defined for this task with multiple hosts, as below:

```
    define service{
            use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use
            host_name                       localhost, host1, host2, host3, host4, host5, host6
            service_description             Root Partition
            check_command                   check_local_disk!20%!10%!/
            contact_groups                  unix-admins,db-admins
            }
```

- The Issue:

Further I tried to test single host i.e. "host2". The current usage of host2 is as follow:

```
    # df -h /
    Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/mapper/rootvg-rootvol   94G   45G   45G  50% /
```

So to get instant emails, I written another service as below, where warning set to <60% and critical set to <40%.

```
    define service{
            use                             local-service
            host_name                       host2
            service_description             Root Partition again
            check_command                   check_local_disk!60%!40%!/
            contact_groups                  dev-admins
            }
```

But still I am not receive any emails for the same.

Where it going wrong.

The "check_local_disk" command is defined as below:

```
    define command{
            command_name    check_local_disk
            command_line    $USER1$/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command definition currently is setup to only check your Nagios server's disk, not the remote hosts (such as host2).  You need to define a new command definition to execute check_disk on the remote host via NRPE (Nagios Remote Plugin Execution).

**On Nagios server, define the following:**

```
define command {
        command_name                    check_remote_disk
        command_line                    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c check_disk -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$
        register                        1
}


define service{
        use                             genric-service
        host_name                       host1, host2, host3, host4, host5, host6
        service_description             Root Partition
        check_command                   check_remote_disk!20%!10%!/
        contact_groups                  unix-admins,db-admins
}
```

Restart the Nagios service.

**On the remote host:**

- Ensure you have NRPE plugin installed.

  - Instructions for Ubuntu:  http://tecadmin.net/install-nrpe-on-ubuntu/
  - Instructions for CentOS / RHEL: http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/03/02/how-to-install-and-configure-nagios-nrpe-in-centos-and-red-hat/
- Ensure there is a command defined for `check_disk` on the remote host.  This is usually included in `nrpe.cfg`, but commented-out.  You'd have to un-comment the line.
- Ensure you have the `check_disk` plugin installed on the remote host.  Mine is located at:  `/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_disk`
- Ensure that `allowed_hosts` field of `nrpe.cfg` includes the IP address / hostname of your Nagios server.
- Ensure that `dont_blame_nrpe` field of `nrpe.cfg` is set to `1` to allow command line arguments to NRPE commands:  `dont_blame_nrpe=1`
- If you made any changes, restart the nrpe service.

Comment: This is perfect ! thanks. Further I want to know, How can I send email at only first check of issue i.e. disk usage goes >90% and stop notification for next check until recovery.

Comment: Modify your service definition and add the following line:  `notification_interval           0`